# Не работает функция по примеру, помогите

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Здраствуйте, суть проблемы в том, что я не могу получить значение функции getActive(), исходящей объекта $brand в коде:

Код Маппера

```
    public function update($brand) {
    if ( !($brand instanceof Brand) ) {
        $this->errors[] = 'Передан объект не класса Brand.';
        return false;
    }
    try {
        $f = $brand->getLogoFilename();
        $query = 'UPDATE `brands` '
               . 'SET `name` = :name, `active` = :active'
               . (!is_null($f) ? ', `logofilename` = :logofilename ' : ' ')
               . 'WHERE `ID` = :ID';
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(':ID', $brand->getID());
        $stmt->bindValue(':name', $brand->getName());

            $stmt->bindValue(':active', $brand->getActive());

        if (!is_null($f)) {$stmt->bindValue(':logofilename', $f);}
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() != 1) {
            $this->errors[] = 'Ошибка обновления информации в базе.';
            return false;
        }
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == '23000') {
            // вставка невозможна из-за дублирования названия (`name` это уникальный ключ)
            $this->errors[] = 'Название марки уже есть в базе.';
            return false;
        }
        throw $e;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Сама функция выглядит ровно так же, как и функция получения имени и картинки предполагаемого бренда, однако они работают, а нужная - нет:

```
public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}
public function getActive() {
    return $this->active;
}
public function getLogoFilename() {
    return $this->logofilename;
}
```

Даже не знаю, что ещё предоставить
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить PDO::PARAM_BOOL

```
$stmt->bindValue(':active', $brand->getActive(), PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
```

Comment: Нет, не хочет, просто выдает 500 ошибку php

Comment: В вашем случае с пространством имен, т.е. \PDO::PARAM_BOOL

Comment: Ну, с этим хотя бы не вылетает, это хорошо, но пишет внутреннюю ошибку, как и до этого "Ошибка обновления информации в базе."

Comment: В таком случае ошибки в коде я не вижу, из приведенного кода следует что сообщение "Ошибка обновления информации в базе." возникает если кол-во обновленных в базе строк не равно 1, обратите внимание. не меньше 1, а не равно 1. То есть больше 1 так же вызовет это сообщение. Если критично именно отследить не обновление, то измените условие на "$stmt->rowCount() < 1". В остальном ищите проблему в логике, может быть действительно не ни одной записи которую нужно обновить по этим условиям, или их больше 1.

Comment: Пока убрал эту ошибку, сейчас нет, ни вылетов, ни ошибок, НО значение в базу не записывается. Функция ничего не передает, если в этом же месте $stmt->bindValue(':active', $brand->getActive(), /PDO::PARAM_BOOL); поменять на $stmt->bindValue(':active', 1) -- то значение записывается

Comment: $stmt->bindValue(':active', (int)$brand->getActive()); А так? Какой тип поля `active` в базе данных? Можете показать что возвращает функция $brand->getActive() если её просто вызвать и присвоить результат в переменную?